# What does this AWS error mean: The Code tab failed to save. Reason: Signature expired: X is now earlier than Y?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

When I uploaded the deployment package into AWS Lambda, and click `Test and Run`, I got the following error after a few minutes:

```
The Code tab failed to save. Reason: Signature expired: 20170327T111954Z is now earlier than 20170327T112115Z (20170327T112615Z - 5 min.)
```

It worked alright when I re-tried the uploaded though(without changing anything)

But, I'm curious about what does this error mean?

Comment: Do you somehow cache some urls? It's saying that your signature was signed more than 5mins before current request.

Comment: @Justinas I don't remember doing :/ . Is it a browser thing? [Using Chrome]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that VM / Docker that was running your code had some clock syncing issues.

Since Signature V4 ( algorithm that you use to authenticate request to amazon ) uses date inside, there always going to be a very very little chance that you hit this error.

If you would be in charge of this VM, I would suggest syncing clocks using `ntpd`. For more details see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-time.html

Answer (score 2):

Believe it or not >> Upload using more fast connection or upload your file to S3 then use the link

it's all about upload session timeout